# Bound helper taking parameter as string not value of property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to Handlebars (and Ember) so this may be me making a tragically simple mistake but I'm feeling confounded enough that I'm hoping someone else can look at this.

I have a simple handlebars bound helper (note: am using **[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)** and the appropriate JS is loaded):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('time', function(context) {
  console.log("time: " + context);
  var aMomentInTime = new moment(context,["YYYY-MM-DD", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"]);
  return aMomentInTime.format("ddd, h:mmA");
});
```

Within an `#each` block in a view template I have the following:

```
{{#each Controller}}
    <p>
        {{time start_time}}<br/>  
        {{start_time}}
    </p>
{{/each}}
```

Where `start_time` is defined as `DS.attr("date")` in the model. In the first line I'm expecting a formatted date based on the value of start_time, sadly the console.log indicates that instead of a date object of start_time (or even a string which had the value of start_time) I'm just getting the string "start_time". What gives?

[image]

As a result of the string coming in, moment.js try's to handle it gracefully and outputs `Sat, 12:00 AM` (aka, it has no idea what date the meaningless string is meant to represent).

In contrast, the `{{start_time}}` reference works correctly and outputs results such as: `2013-07-09 08:00:06`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `registerHelper` does not support bindings. Use `registerBoundHelper` or just `helper`.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('time', function(context) {
  console.log("time: " + context);
  var aMomentInTime = new moment(context,["YYYY-MM-DD", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"]);
  return aMomentInTime.format("ddd, h:mmA");
});
```